# How to retrieve OUTSIDE the "foreach" loop of my PHP Code, the VERY FIRST image of the page?

Tags: php, foreach

With `DomDocument` and knowing that the variable `$img_wiki_collected_src` which represents the links or the URL of each image of the page, **I try to collect OUTSIDE THE `foreach`, the very first image of the Page** but that does not work when I do `echo $img_wiki_collected_src` (*outside the `foreach` loop*), *instead it's the URL of the last image on the page that's displayed **instead of the first image I'm looking to to display.***

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$parser = new DOMDocument();
$parser->loadHTMLFile("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alibaba_Group");
$get_img_tags = $parser->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($get_img_tags as $img_collected) {
    $img_wikiped_src = $img_collected->getAttribute("src");
    $img_wiki_collected_src = createLink($img_wikiped_src, $url);
    $img_collected->setAttribute('src', $img_wiki_collected_src);
}
```

How then, to display OUTSIDE THE `foreach`, the URL of **THE VERY FIRST IMAGE** of the page knowing once again that it is the variable `$img_wiki_collected_src` which represents the link of each image of the page using the loop `foreach` ?

How to display **out of the `foreach` loop the first image** of the page ?

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this just before the foreach loop:

```
$first_image_src = $get_img_tags[0]->getAttribute("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for yor answer. **But, I get the following error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_values() expects parameter 1 to
> be array, object given in C:\laragon\www\test.php:239 Stack trace: #0
> C:\laragon\www\test.php(239): array_values(Object(DOMNodeList)) #1
> {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 239

**When I do:**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$parser = new DOMDocument();
$parser->loadHTMLFile("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alibaba_Group");
$get_img_tags = $parser->getElementsByTagName("img");
$first_image_colected_src = createLink(array_values($get_img_tags)[0]->getAttribute("src"));
foreach($get_img_tags as $img_collected) {
    $img_wikiped_src = $img_collected->getAttribute("src");
    $img_wiki_collected_src = createLink($img_wikiped_src, $url);
    $img_collected->setAttribute('src', $img_wiki_collected_src);
}

echo $first_image_colected_src;
```

So, It doesn't work.

Help please.